# Flask post request from a route

Tags: python-3.x, flask, request

Is it possible to do a post request from one route in flask to another route? A user sends in data I will look up data then submit that data to another route.  Getting `Internal Server Error` log just has `failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`.  I know the route works if i remove the requests line I see `found you`.

```
@app.route('/route/<string:uname>', endpoint = 'uname')
def uname():
    d={}
    d['fname']='data'
    d['lname']='data'

    requests.post(url='https:site.com/test/', data = data)
return 'found you'
@app.route('test', endpoint = 'test', methods = ['POST','GET'])   
def test():
return "submitted to test"
```

***** Added `verify=False` to the requests.post line and it just hangs and ties up the service.  I have to restart the service for the site to start working.

Comment: Making an HTTP-request from your server to your server is an incorrect approach. Correct approach is to reuse your own code and convert an HTTP-request into a function call. Move the code from the `test()` method to a separate function and call it from the `uname` and `test`.

Comment: will do, I was just curious if it was even possible.

Comment: It _is_ possible, but for it to work you'll need minimum 2 instances of your app to be running (usually done with a WSGI server like Gunicorn). `111: Connection refused` error may be because there is no application to serve a request to `/test` because the only one you have is used to serve uname request which be freed until second request is sent. So, to process a single request to uname you'll need 2 instances of your app.